# Stored Procedure to copy data from master database to division databases

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We have a master database which keeps global tables for all divisions. It also has a division table which contains database name and other connection parameters.

All divisions have separate databases which contain division specific tables and also global tables which are copy of global tables from master database.

We are looking to create a dynamic stored procedure which will run as a job each day and check if any global tables have been updated in master database. If yes, the data will be copied from global tables to division tables for each division in a loop.

Any help or pointers in developing this will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to use SQL Server replication. Both [transactional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx) and [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx) replication can fit the bill. Create a publication at the master and have each division create a filtered subscription, see [Filter Published Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775.aspx).

You cannot do this with a 'stored procedure' because you don't have the infrastructure to track changes, you cannot compare data remotely efficiently for deltas, you lack a means of reliable delivery of deltas, you don't have a proper monitoring and deployment tool set, you don't have means to detect and act on conflicts etc etc etc. Do not reinvent the wheel, specially such an old and well tested wheel.